# Rails generate last 12 months statments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My requirement is to provide last 12 month downloadable statements in form of excel sheets.
I've written sql statement in the model something like this. I need some ideas how to pass the values dynamically and break them into 12 links to show in the view

```
class AwsCostDetailsController < ApplicationController
  @products = AwsCostDetails.group(:group_name,:cost_date).sum(:unblendedcost)
end

View 
 Jan-14
 Feb-14
 Mar-14
  ....
  ...
 Dec-14

 upon clicking the link the excel file shall be downloaded which will have following columns
   Group Name | Cost | month-year
```

How do I use above method in model  and show last month downloadable links in view.Hope I explained well.

Comment: Please, be *extremely* careful when inlining values in your SQL like that. Most of the time these can be re-written as AREL expressions without the need for raw SQL.

Comment: I completely agree with @tadman. Please optimize your query using Arel.   Can you state what exactly do you want as in what columns do you want to fetch from the table and under what conditions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.But at this point my primary focus is getting the output.Shall revisit the code before deploying in QA.

Comment: For your convenience updated the code in Arel format.@products = AwsCostDetails.group(:group_name,:cost_date).sum(:unblendedcost)